# Azure VPN login happens with out MFA

Tags: azure, vpn, openvpn

I have configured Virtual network gateway with Azure AD authentication OpenVPN SSL tunnel. While connecting via AzureVPN application using my office mail ID i'm not asked for MFA even though it is enforced by Administrator to ask MFA when ever a user logs in, plus i'm not even prompted for my password also. Why is this happening is it by design like this?

Comment: What is User type in Azure AD users? Is Guest or Member? Is this user enabled MFA like [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-mfa#peruser)? If the Set `User assignment required` to `Yes` in [Configure sign-in settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-mfa#enablesign), you need to add this user to this group `users and groups`. Ps, what do you mean `even prompted for my password `? can you access your VPN connection successfully and just ignore the password? Can you login again via private mode or clear the cache in browser?

Comment: I tried with one member and one guest user to test this and both are part of VPN as User assignment is set to yes. Yes via VPN i'm able to connect and access resources but not sure why MFA is never prompted even though it is enforced by admin for all users.

Not Prompted for password: While connecting a window pops up to select the login account if i select my account or enter guest user details it just connects without password.

Comment: Also what kind of permission i need to access all the option of AzureVPN(Enterprise Application), as of now i'm Application Administrator which is supposed to give me access to all aspects of application but parts like Self Service, Conditional Access, Token Encryption, Sign-Ins, Audit Logs, Provisioning Logs are Grayed out for me. I was part of Security reader role which gave me access to all mentioned sections and everything else except Token Encryption and Self Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So If a User(AD Member) login from *Azure AD registered*, *Azure AD joined*, *Hybrid Azure AD joined* device they'll not be prompted for MFA since MFA token is already claimed(they'll be asked if token not claimed) if MFA is still needed then conditional access needs to be applied.

[image]

or Click on use different account so that new token is needed to be claimed and MFA is prompted.

**Security reader role** should be enough to access almost all the part of the this application.